# Can't access localhost with file_get_contents in wordpress container

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, localhost

Running Wordpress 5.2.2 with docker compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:5.2.2
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./uploads:/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads
      - ./plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins
      - ./themes:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes
      - ./wp-config.php:/var/www/html/wp-config.php
```

This is running the container on localhost:8000.
When I attempt to use `file_get_contents` on a url, e.g:
`file_get_contents('http://localhost:8000/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/discover.svg');`
I get the error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://localhost:8000/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/discover.svg): failed to open stream: Cannot assign requested address in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/mytheme/test/php
```

I've tried the following php ini settings in the wp-config:

```
@ini_set( 'allow_url_fopen', true);
@ini_set( 'allow_url_include', true);
```

Any help would be appreciated